# Enumerate exhibits unexpected behavior when renamed

Tags: environments, enumerate, debugging, bugs

Enumerate exhibits unexpected behavior when renamed
In the example below I renamed `enumerate` to `enum` for brevity.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\newcommand{\enum}{\enumerate}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item A
\item B
\item C
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enum}
\item A
\item B
\item C
\end{enum}

%\begin{\enum}
%\item A
%\item B
%\item C
%\end{\enum}

\end{document}
```

However the outputs of when the fullname is used and shortname is used are different. As expected, fullname gives

```
    1. A
    2. B
    3. C
```

But shortname gives

```
    1. A
    2. B
3. C
```

And `\enum` does not compile. For some other environments shortnames do not work at all.  Can someone explain why this happens and how to properly shorten environment names?

Comment: you need to copy the whole environment, including the end code. But don't do it.  It is easy to create clashes with existing commands and you make your code less readable for other if you are looking for help (as you do now). Better setup your editor so that it automatically creates such environments and eases the typing.

Comment: The package defines a macro `\@@enum@` to handle optional arguments. Your definition may clash with that. See page 3 of the `enumerate` package documentation on CTAN

Comment: @EladDen That isn't a problem here

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `\end{enum}` wants to execute `\endenum` and, since the token is undefined, TeX treats it as `\relax` (because `\csname` is used).

Thus `\endenumerate` never gets executed and you're left with wrong output.

Add `\let\endenum\endenumerate`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\newcommand{\enum}{\enumerate}
\let\endenum\endenumerate

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item A
\item B
\item C
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enum}
\item A
\item B
\item C
\end{enum}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I recommend using the more flexible `enumitem` package instead of `enumerate`.

Don't even try `\begin{\enum}`. It's ***very*** wrong.